# How does this Python Generator work?

Tags: python, generator

Can someone please explain what this generator code is doing?

```
>>> def f():
...     return next((i for i in [{'a':1, 'b':2}, {'c':3, 'd':4}]))
...
>>> t = f()
>>> for item in t:
...     print(item)
...
a
b
>>> t
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>>
```

Actually, is this function designed to return only a single value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Can someone please explain what this generator code is doing?*

```
(i for i in [{'a':1, 'b':2}, {'c':3, 'd':4}])
```

This is the syntax for a generator comprehension. Try iterating over it like this:

```
In [205]: for x in (i for i in [{'a':1, 'b':2}, {'c':3, 'd':4}]):
 ...:     print(x)
 ...:     
{'b': 2, 'a': 1}
{'d': 4, 'c': 3}
```

The `next()` function returns the next item from the generator. From the documentation of [`next`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next):

> `next(iterator[, default])`
>
> Retrieve the next item from the iterator by calling its `next()` method.
>   If default is given, it is returned if the iterator is exhausted,
>   otherwise StopIteration is raised.

In this case, what is returned is

```
{'a':1, 'b':2}
```

This is a dictionary. If you use a `for` loop on this as you do, you iterate over the keys, so you print out `a`, and `b` in turn (if you're on python3.6) because the order of keys is guaranteed. On older python versions, you will print the keys in some arbitrary order.

> *Actually, is this function designed to return only a single value?*

Yes it is. As an exercise, try changing `return` to `yield from`, like this:

```
def f():
    yield from (i for i in [{'a':1, 'b':2}, {'c':3, 'd':4}]))
```

Comment: Thanks. Surprisingly, yield returns the first item in the dictionary.

Comment: It may be worth noting that the order the keys are iterated from the dictionary is not guaranteed. In Python versions prior to 3.6, it is likely to be random. In 3.6 itself, the keys will be yielded in the order they were added to the dictionary, but this is considered an implementation detail, not something you should rely upon. That might change in 3.7 or some later version (it's likely to happen, but it hasn't been decided yet).

Comment: >>> def f():
...     yield next((i for i in [{'a':1, 'b':2}, {'c':3, 'd':4}]))
...
>>> t = f()
>>> for item in t:
...     print(item)
...
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>>

Comment: @user3267989 Made a small change. I think I should have been more specific.

Comment: @Blckknght Thanks for that bit. Added it in!

Comment: Thanks COLDSPEED and Blckknght. Learnt smth new tonight.